# Swapping data frame values randomly between different deciles of the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, swap, percentile

Its a bit complicated to explain, so I hope it is clear enough, but if not I'll try and expand more.

So I have a data-frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(index=sort(runif(300, -10,10)), v1=runif(300, -2,-1), v2=runif(300, 1,2))
```

It gives us a 3-column 300-row df. The first column ("index") contains sorted values from -10 to 10, and the next two columns ("v1"/"v2") contain random numeric values that are not important for this issue.

Now I classify my df rows into deciles according to the index column, (e.g. decile 1: places 1-30, decile 2: places 31-60) and I want to swap randomly between the rows such that all the 1st decile values are swapped randomly with the 6th decile, all 2nd decile values are swapped randomly with the 7th decile, and so on. When I say swapped I mean that the index value remains in its place but the v1 and v2 values are swapped (still coupled) with the v1 and v2 of a random row in the appropriate decile.

For example, the v1 and v2 of the first row in the df (and thus from the 1st decile), will be swapped with the v1 and v2 of the 160th row in the df (6th decile), the v1 and v2 of the second row in the df (1st decile) will be swapped with the v1 and v2 of the 175th row in the df (also 6th decile), the v1 and v2 of the 31st row in the df (2nd decile) will be swapped with the v1 and v2 of the 186th row in the df (7th decile) and so on so all of the v1+v2 values have changed places randomly to their appropriate new decile.

Hope it's clear. I've been trying to solve it for hours and couldn't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you  just select a pair of index values and swap them? Then sort the data frame by index using `order()`, when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Using `order()` to sort by two indices, one being the rearranged deciles, the other one random.

```
set.seed(123)
dtf <- data.frame(round(cbind(index=sort(runif(20, -10, 10)), 
                                 v1=runif(20, 0, 5), 
                                 v2=runif(20, 5, 10)), 2))
ea <- nrow(dtf)/10

# Deciles shifted by 5
d <- rep(((1:10 + 4) %% 10) + 1, each=ea)

# Random index within decile
r <- c(replicate(10, sample(ea)))

cbind(dtf, z=dtf[order(d, r), -1])
#    index   v1   v2 z.v1 z.v2
# 12 -9.16 4.45 5.71 4.51 7.21
# 11 -9.09 3.46 7.07 4.82 5.23
# 14 -7.94 3.20 7.07 3.98 5.61
# 13 -5.08 4.97 6.84 3.45 8.99
# 15 -4.25 3.28 5.76 0.12 7.80
# 16 -3.44 3.54 5.69 2.39 6.03
# 17 -1.82 2.72 6.17 3.79 5.64
# 18 -0.93 2.97 7.33 1.08 8.77
# 19 -0.87 1.45 6.33 1.59 9.48
# 20  0.56 0.74 9.29 1.16 6.87
# 2   1.03 4.82 5.23 3.46 7.07
# 1   1.45 4.51 7.21 4.45 5.71
# 3   3.55 3.45 8.99 3.20 7.07
# 4   5.77 3.98 5.61 4.97 6.84
# 6   7.66 0.12 7.80 3.54 5.69
# 5   7.85 2.39 6.03 3.28 5.76
# 8   8.00 3.79 5.64 2.97 7.33
# 7   8.81 1.08 8.77 2.72 6.17
# 10  9.09 1.59 9.48 0.74 9.29
# 9   9.14 1.16 6.87 1.45 6.33
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you need.

```
swapByBlocks <- function(df, blockSize = 30, nblocks = 10){
    if((nrow(df) != blockSize*nblocks) || nblocks %%2) stop("Undefined behaviour")
    swappedDF <- df[c((nrow(df)/2 +1):nrow(df), 1:(nrow(df)/2)),]
    ndxMat <- sapply(1:(nblocks/2),function(dummy) sample(1:blockSize))
    for(i in 1:ncol(ndxMat)) {
        swappedDF[(i-1)*blockSize + 1:blockSize, ] <- swappedDF[((i-1)*blockSize + 1:blockSize)[ndxMat[,i]], ]
        swappedDF[(i+nblocks/2-1)*blockSize + 1:blockSize, ] <- swappedDF[((i+nblocks/2-1)*blockSize + 1:blockSize)[order(ndxMat[,i])], ]
    }   
    return(swappedDF)                
}
```

A small case where you can check how it works:

```
res <- swapByBlocks(df[1:18,], blockSize = 3, nblocks = 6)
> df[1:18,]
       index        v1       v2
1  -9.859624 -1.657779 1.954094
2  -9.774898 -1.015825 1.006341
3  -9.624402 -1.713754 1.527065
4  -9.441129 -1.891834 1.803793
5  -9.424195 -1.125674 1.581199
6  -8.890537 -1.142044 1.219111
7  -8.838012 -1.173445 1.013408
8  -8.296938 -1.780396 1.570550
9  -8.172076 -1.789056 1.178596
10 -7.671897 -1.988539 1.690468
11 -7.655868 -1.095662 1.876414
12 -7.450011 -1.337443 1.632104
13 -7.204528 -1.880350 1.408944
14 -7.085862 -1.232293 1.593247
15 -7.030691 -1.087031 1.924306
16 -6.989892 -1.639967 1.495058
17 -6.978945 -1.395340 1.872944
18 -6.930379 -1.841031 1.061046
> res
       index        v1       v2
10 -7.450011 -1.337443 1.632104
11 -7.655868 -1.095662 1.876414
12 -7.671897 -1.988539 1.690468
13 -7.030691 -1.087031 1.924306
14 -7.085862 -1.232293 1.593247
15 -7.204528 -1.880350 1.408944
16 -6.989892 -1.639967 1.495058
17 -6.930379 -1.841031 1.061046
18 -6.978945 -1.395340 1.872944
1  -9.624402 -1.713754 1.527065
2  -9.774898 -1.015825 1.006341
3  -9.859624 -1.657779 1.954094
4  -8.890537 -1.142044 1.219111
5  -9.424195 -1.125674 1.581199
6  -9.441129 -1.891834 1.803793
7  -8.838012 -1.173445 1.013408
8  -8.172076 -1.789056 1.178596
9  -8.296938 -1.780396 1.570550
>
```

Here there are 18 rows with six blocks of three numbers each. Rows 1 to 3 get swapped with rows 10 to 12, rows 4 to 6 with rows 13 to 15 and rows 4
7 to 9 with rows 16 to 17.